# sequelize selecting columns that are not mentioned in the model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have 2 tables that are in a 1 to many relationship (course has many subjects), and before doing a delete operation on subject I want to check if it is associated with any course, so here are my models:

Course:

```
    'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Course = sequelize.define('Course', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    desc: DataTypes.TEXT
  }, {});
  Course.associate = function(models) {
    Course.belongsToMany(models.Subject, {
        through: 'courseSubjects'
    });

    Course.hasMany(models.Batch)
  };
  return Course;
};
```

and subject:

```
    'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Subject = sequelize.define('Subject', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    desc: DataTypes.TEXT
  }, {});

  Subject.associate = function(models) {
    Subject.belongsToMany(models.Module, {
        through: 'subjectModules'
    });

    Subject.belongsToMany(models.Course, {
        through: 'courseSubjects',
    });
  };
  return Subject;
};
```

So this is the statement I am calling:

```
res.status(200).send(subject.getCourses())
```

and getting error:

> Executing (default): SELECT `Course`.`id`, `Course`.`name`, `Course`.`desc`, `Course`.`createdAt`, `Course`.`updatedAt`, `Course`.`courseId`, `courseSubjects`.`createdAt` AS `courseSubjects.createdAt`, `courseSubjects`.`updatedAt` AS `courseSubjects.updatedAt`, `courseSubjects`.`CourseId` AS `courseSubjects.CourseId`, `courseSubjects`.`SubjectId` AS `courseSubjects.SubjectId` FROM `Courses` AS `Course` INNER JOIN `courseSubjects` AS `courseSubjects` ON `Course`.`id` = `courseSubjects`.`CourseId` AND `courseSubjects`.`SubjectId` = 34;
>   [0] Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'Course.courseId' in 'field list'

I do not understand why is it trying to select 'courseId'.. Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add relation into course table as well, it will remove the 'courseId' column from select.